# jQuery CSS Opacity Animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I'm trying to create a simple fading slideshow with five slides that repeats when finished.

I feel like what I've got should work, but it's not.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        function playslide(){

            setTimeout(function(){
            $("#slide-two").animate({"opacity":"1"}, 2000, 'swing').delay(11000).animate({"opacity":"0"}, 1, 'swing')}, 10000);
            setTimeout(function(){
            $("#slide-three").animate({"opacity":"1"}, 2000, 'swing').delay(11000).animate({"opacity":"0"}, 1, 'swing')}, 20000);
            setTimeout(function(){
            $("#slide-four").animate({"opacity":"1"}, 2000, 'swing').delay(11000).animate({"opacity":"0"}, 1, 'swing')}, 30000);
            setTimeout(function(){
            $("#slide-five").animate({"opacity":"1"}, 2000, 'swing').delay(11000).animate({"opacity":"0"}, 2000, 'swing')}, 40000);

        }

        playslide();

        });
</script>
```

The idea is that the first slide will always have its opacity set to 1, so that when the last slide fades out, it's as if it's starting again. Each slide will hold for 10 seconds before fading out and after each slide fades in, the previous slide's opacity will be set back to 0 ready for the next time it repeats.

I hope it's not an obvious mistake. Apologies if it is...

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney https://jsfiddle.net/g9o4nfbL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please why not use a `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` instead?

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $("#slide-two").fadeIn(400, function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $("#slide-two").fadeOut(function () {
      $("#slide-three").fadeIn(400, function () {
        // So on...
      });
    }, 1000);
  });
}, 1000);
```

Better to use these functions for doing it instead of you manually animating opacity.

Comment: I had done this in the past and for some reason it didn't work the way I'd wanted it to. Just tried again and it's works great, weird. Thanks for this suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/sk8ruo3u/

here's how I would do it

```
var list = ['.one','.two','.three','.four'];

$.each(list, function(index, value){
    changeOpacity(value, index*1000);    
});

function changeOpacity(target, timeout) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(target).animate({
            opacity: 0.05
        }, 1000);
    }, timeout);
};
```